# docx4j / xlsx4j - why does Row ignore cells with an empty value

Tags: java, excel, jaxb, xlsx, docx4j

I'm currently using **org.docx4j:docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl:11.2.9** in a project.

While iterating over an Excel sheet, I need to read all the cell values, even the ones that are empty.

```
        File excelFile = new File("c:\report.xlsx");
        SpreadsheetMLPackage xlsxPkg = SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(excelFile);
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = xlsxPkg.getWorkbookPart();
        WorksheetPart sheet = workbookPart.getWorksheet(0);
        Worksheet ws = sheet.getContents();
        SheetData data = ws.getSheetData();
        data.getRow().forEach(row -> {
            row.getC().forEach(cell -> {
                LOG.debug(cell.getR());
            });
        });
```

I'm noticing in the LOG output that the empty cells are simply not there. So this means that the call to `row.getC()` is returning a reduced number of cells. Here's what part of the log output looks like. I've added in the cell **R** values that are missing.

```
2021-09-03 17:17:39,026 DEBUG ExcelParser [Test worker] Z2
2021-09-03 17:17:39,026 DEBUG ExcelParser [Test worker] AA2
                                                            AB2  <------- missing
2021-09-03 17:17:39,026 DEBUG ExcelParser [Test worker] AC2
                                                            AD2  <------- missing
2021-09-03 17:17:39,026 DEBUG ExcelParser [Test worker] AE2
                                                            AF2  <------- missing
2021-09-03 17:17:39,026 DEBUG ExcelParser [Test worker] AG2
2021-09-03 17:17:39,026 DEBUG ExcelParser [Test worker] AH2
2021-09-03 17:17:39,026 DEBUG ExcelParser [Test worker] AI2
2021-09-03 17:17:39,026 DEBUG ExcelParser [Test worker] AJ2
2021-09-03 17:17:39,026 DEBUG ExcelParser [Test worker] AK2
2021-09-03 17:17:39,026 DEBUG ExcelParser [Test worker] AL2
```

Any ideas what's causing this? I didn't find any configuration that I should apply. The problem is that I need to re-create the sheet later, but because the empty cells are missing, this is shifting other values and putting them in the wrong column.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much value in storing empty cells in an Excel file, therefore only cells with some sort of content are stored in the file. This is not a bug, it is simply how it is implemented.

You can use this code, if you expect rows to be an array-like structure, where all cells (filled or empty) have a position. We start with an array, where all positions are filled with null values. Then we put all the cells that have a value into the array at the right position.

```
public Cell[] getRow(Row row) {
  Cell[] row = new Cell[100]; // whatever number you choose as last column
  row.getC().forEach(cell -> {
    row[addresstoColumnNumber(cell.getR())] = cell;
  });
  return row;
}

public int addressToColumnNumber(String address) {
  String columnString = address.replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
  int number = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < columnString.length(); i++) {
    number = number * 26 + (columnString.charAt(i) - ('A'-1));
  }
  return number - 1; // array index is zero-based
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mario, but I respectfully disagree. I cannot know ahead of time which cells will have empty values. And as the caller to get the cells, I think it's only fair to get the data back as it is actually represented in the Excel sheet. The absence of data for a given column is still relevant. And to have data shifted into incorrect columns is even more alarming.

Comment: I added some sample code to my answer, that fills the 'holes' in a row with null values, so that you will not have a problem with shifting cells.